# Monorepo, Travis and Matrix builds: How do I build a specific path only when it changes?

Tags: build, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I have a single repo with several (`java/gradle`) projects:

```
project-a/
project-b/
project-c/
```

I would like to create a matrix build configuration, with one build per project.  And I only want to build that project if there have been changes to it.

Is this possible?

I can easily create a script that checks if a folder has been affected by using `$TRAVIS_COMMIT_RANGE`.  But how would I use this in `.travis.yml`?

#### EDIT

There's an issue in Travis for [adding support for include/exclude paths for when to trigger builds](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/6301). With matrix support, this would solve my issue.

Comment: Have you read this recently? https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#build-matrix

Answer (score 1):

You essentially ask about a conditional build in one form or another. Unfortunately [the documentation about conditional builds](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/conditional-builds-stages-jobs/) states that

> Jobs created via matrix expansion currently cannot have conditions.

... and even if it supported that, I don't see any easy way to check for a commit path in [the list of supported conditions](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/conditions-v1).

Nonetheless it is possible to achieve that process with their API. You can create a build configuration which aims to just run your script, and check which subproject needs to be built now. This meta build script can [trigger a travis build via the API](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/triggering-builds/). On that doc page you can find an example of how to trigger a particular job from your matrix.